# Andy difference between two Lists of Custom Classes?

Tags: vb.net

I'm porting an application from VBA to VB.Net, and switched from 2 generic 2D arrays to 2 Lists of custom classes, lst1 & lst2. (The objects are intentionally different as they are for different purposes.)  Through debugging I took two different approaches to each. Both seem to work, but I'm wondering if/how they are different under the hood. Also happy to take suggestions to impove them/style.  TIA.

```
Module SOExampleCode

''' <summary>
''' Object1
''' </summary>
Public Class o1
    Public Property Idx As Long                 'Extra Index if needed
    Public Property LabelTop As String            'Text Label
    Public Property PrdStartDt As Date            'PeriodStart Date
    Public Property PostnX As Double            'Position

    Sub Clear()
        Idx = 0
        LabelTop = ""
        PrdStartDt = Nothing
        PostnX = 0
    End Sub

End Class

''' <summary>
''' Object2
''' </summary>
Public Class o2
    Public Property Idx As Long             'Extra Index if needed
    Public Property RowNum As Long          'Number of this row in the chart
    Public Property Label As String      'Text Label - optional
    Public Property PostnY As Double        'Position in points on Y axis

    Sub New(Optional ByVal Idx As Long = 0, Optional ByVal RowNum As Long = 0, Optional ByVal Label As String = "",
            Optional ByVal PostnY As Double = 0)
        _Idx = Idx
        _RowNum = RowNum
        _Label = Label
        _PostnY = PostnY

    End Sub

    Sub Clear()
        Idx = 0
        RowNum = 0
        Label = ""
        PostnY = 0
    End Sub

End Class



Public lst1 As New List(Of o1)
Public lst2 As New List(Of o2)



Sub MainLoad()
    Dim limit1 As Long
    Dim limit2 As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim tmp1 As o1
    Dim str1 As String
    Dim dt1 As Date


    'Loading of List 1 / Object 1
    For i = 1 To limit1
        tmp1 = New o1
        With tmp1
            .Idx = i
            .LabelTop = str1
            .PrdStartDt = dt1
            .PostnX = 123.456

            lst1.Add(tmp1)
        End With
    Next i


    'Loading of List 2 / Object 2
    For i = 1 To limit2
        lst2.Add(New o2(Idx:=i, RowNum:=100 + i, Label:=str1, PostnY:=654.321))
    Next i

End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: The differences between the two lists: `lst1` and `lst2` are two different objects that contain collections of different objects. Each object in each collection is a different reference. -- Not exactly clear what the question is actually about.

Comment: OK. 1) By instantiating tmp1 each loop1/lst1, am I slowing the process and consuming more memory than needed? Or more than in loop2/lst2?

Comment: Are you asking which method of constructing the objects is better?

Comment: 2) Why did I need to add a specific New() method to o2?  I thought VB.Net handled that behind the scenes when using properties?  (Yes, I used example code I didn't fully understand)

Comment: You're creating a new instance of `o1` and `o2` in both cases. -- A class object is instantiated using the new() keyword. If you don't assign values to the properties, default values are used. Reference types will be null (nothing) if not instantiated (same for nullable value types).

Comment: @Hursey Yes, but also which is the better approach to building the lists for later use?  Or are they simply different paths to the identical end?

Comment: Straight personal style which way you do it, both methods achieve the same thing.  Might be very minor performance differences one way or the other, but probably not enough to worry about